# Asynchronous git hook?

Tags: git, githooks

I execute unit tests on post-receive but don't want the user to wait for it.

I tried the suggestions from the git-user mailing list ("just `&` it") but this is not working: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-users/CFshrDgYYzE

git seems to wait for the bash script to exit even if I just put this in hooks/post-receive:

```
exec-unit-tests.sh &
```

Comment: have you tried the other ways suggested in that post, e.g. using cron to schedule the async job? something like `at` to schedule jobs on demand (and not far in the future) might also be worth looking into

Comment: that might also work, i didn't try it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This worked for me. `&` and the stdout & stderr pipe must be closed:

```
long-running-command >&- 2>&- &
```

In order to put the command in the background, both `stdout` AND `stderr` must be closed. If either of them is left open the process won't be in the background, and the commit operation won't complete until the hook script is finished.

A lazy alternative approach is to simply redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`:

```
long-running-command >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This is a bit less clean, but perhaps easier to understand and remember, and it has the same effect.

Comment: found here: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Background-processes-in-post-receive-hook-td6235357.html

Comment: Actually both `stdout` AND `stderr` must be closed (like your answer already does it). If either of them is left open the process won't be in the background. Personally I use `>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &` to get the same effect because it's easier to know what that does without looking up in `man bash`.

Comment: i like your /dev/null solution better! please make it an answer

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your sportsmanship :) But you answered first and you deserve the glory ;-) I appended my version to yours, feel free to make further changes if you want. I will delete this and my previous comments a bit later to clean up.

Comment: Neither of these commands work now. There may have been an update to git hooks since this answer was posted, because now it appears that git hook scripts always wait until all subprocesses are complete before returning. That appears to happen even when using a python script as the git hook.

Comment: What is `&-` in this context? ....... Found it: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: For me using `long-running-command >&- 2>&- &` _did_ prevent Git from waiting for the script (yay!), but it also prevented the script from creating the expected output. Maybe because the program called in the script is using stdout for the output?

"post-commit" content (on Win10):
`#!/bin/sh`
`path\myScript.bat >&- 2>&- &`

"myScript.bat" content:
`title Run other app automatically`
`start path\someoneElsesApp.exe -arg1 -arg2 "inputFile1.xml" "inputFile2.xml" "outputFile.txt"`