# How can I run the git post-receive-email in the background?

Tags: git, githooks

I have a post-receive hook that just calls /usr/share/git-core/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email

I'd like it to run in the background so that git does not get delayed after a commit. I've tried various techniques (exec, piping to "at now", nohup) but when I use any of these techniques no email gets sent. I suspect this has something to do with the use of stdin to pass in the args to the hook.

I guess I need to capture stdin but I've no idea how to do that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I might add that the suggestions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727315/asynchronous-git-hook do not work. In my situation, using any of the techniques I described to put the hook in the background does allow git to continue immediately (i.e, it doesn't get blocked, unlike what is being reported in the other thread) but an email never gets sent out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is probably not the answer you want, you could decouple the hook from the mail delivery using cron and a mail delivery script, dropping your desired email into a directory and having your script pick it up. If you didnt want to wait for the cron every-minute boundary,  you could hack up a daemon that uses inotify to monitor that directory for dropped files.

Comment: Actually this is essentially what I ended up doing. I tried all sorts of ways to get it working properly (a number of suggestions on the reddit form where I also asked this question - http://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/2c4ral/i_asked_about_running_git_mail_notifications_in/) but ultimately I just set up a basic notifier with mailx that doesn't depend on the git args and that works. I don't really need to know about the actual changes via email --- just knowing the repo changed is sufficient.